# Create a variable in a makefile by reading contents of another file

Tags: makefile

How can I create a variable on-the-fly from makefile, the value of which would be the entire contents of another data file.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Assuming GNU make:

```
file := whatever.txt
variable := $(shell cat ${file})
```

Comment: @ceving Use the standard GNU make. Solaris make is a non-portable application.

Comment: Gnu make is neither standard nor more portable than solaris make. "Popular" is your word. If we seriously consider portability and standard conformation, stick with posix.

Comment: I'd go with "Popular" in this case - non-GNU Make is just too primitive. If you're aiming to continue supporting 1990s operating systems, then @bb-generation's answer is probably what you need (though it will get you in trouble in many cases). In all other cases, GNU Make is either easily available or - more likely - the default, so please make use of it.

Comment: GNU make runs anywhere so yes it's much more portable than any other make. "standard" can be subjective, granted.

Comment: the braces around the file variable are new for me. is this standard make? I would use `$(file)` instead of `${file}` - but both work. does anyone know the difference?

Comment: @DanielAlder GNU Make manual is where you look for answers for such basic questions.

Answer (score 56):

I'm guessing that you like to set a variable in your Makefile to the contents of another file:

```
FILE=test.txt
VARIABLE=`cat $(FILE)`

target:
    echo $(VARIABLE)
```

Comment: That's what I have been trying but I get the error: "'VARIABLE' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Please keep in mind that I am using GNU make Windows and I am trying to do this from one of my Targets:

    all:
        VARIABLE=`cat $(PATH_TO_MY_DATA_FILE)`

Comment: You have put the variable definition above the `all:`, right?
[edit] Just edited the answer to my local test-Makefile which works using GNU Make Windows 3.81

Comment: Actually, I cannot put the VARIABLE definition above all: because PATH_TO_MY_DATA_FILE does not exist until some commands have been run in the all: target.

As an alternative, what I have done is that I have split things up into two makefiles (created a sub-make) and declared the VARIABLE at the top of the sub-make and it now works like a charm.

Comment: This is a wrong answer. The value of `VARIABLE` is a string ``cat $(FILE)`` (in quotes) which only gets expanded in a recipe by the shell. Try printing the value of it like `$(info ${VARIABLE})`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin It is not wrong. You just have to consider `VARIABLE` as a promise. This is the only version which works with older versions of `make`. Both `:=` and `$(shell ...)` are GNU extensions.

Comment: @ceving Original question is _variable ... the value of which would be the entire contents of another data file_. In other words, the value is the contents, not the command to read the contents.

Comment: Downvoted. This will execute `cat` every time the rule is executed. This is usually not be intended and should be warned against, because it's slow. Besides, if the file is a pipe, it has unintended side-effects. The assignment should be with `:=` so that the rule would not get evaluated when the variable is replaced but when the variable is defined.  The replacement value should be `$(shell cat $(FILE))` so that the `cat` command is executed in-place by make, not later by the recipe rules.

Comment: Why do people on here always assume that everyone in the world runs a UNIX / Linux-based system that has stuff like cat??

Comment: as @MaximEgorushkin says, this _is_ the wrong answer.  Although this _will_ work in shell sections of a makefile, if you use the value elsewhere, for example in filename, or if you use it within single quotes in the shell then the value you will get is exactly `cat $(FILE)` which is horribly wrong.

Comment: @antred , make is part of the standard UNIX/POSIX toolset which also includes cat.  If you install make it's normal to install all the other basic tools and there are very rare circumstances where that will cause any difficulties.  Relying on `cat` rather than complex alternate rules will make your makefiles much simpler to understand and almost as portable or sometimes more portable.

Answer (score 47):

GNU make version 4.2 supports file reading operation, so with respect to [Maxim Egorushkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/412080/maxim-egorushkin)'s great answer there is an optional way to solve this problem now:

```
FILE     := test.txt
variable :=$(file < $(FILE))
```

Comment: Fixed an error. Variable names are case-sensitive. The names ‘foo’, ‘FOO’, and ‘Foo’ all refer to different variables. (https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Using-Variables.html)

Comment: quotes are also not needed, $(file < "$(FILE)") tries to open "test.txt".

Comment: This is superior to the "shell cat" answers in the case where the file contains newlines and you want them to be preserved

Comment: This is a better solution because it is much faster!

Answer (score 16):

`cat` doesn't exist on Windows. Solution that works for Linux and Windows:

```
cat := $(if $(filter $(OS),Windows_NT),type,cat)
variable := $(shell $(cat) filename)
```

Explanation:
 Seems like On Windows there is always `OS` environment variable defined to be equal to 'Windows_NT'. This way, for Windows `type` command is used, for non-Windows `cat` is used.

Answer (score 15):

Much simpler since `$(file op filename)` was added:

```
VARIABLE = $(file < my_file.txt)
```

Manual page here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Function.html#index-file_002c-reading-from

Comment: This worked for me under GNU Make 4.2.1, unlike the other suggested solutions :)

Comment: This was introduced in GNU Make 4, and macOS still ships with 3.81 in 2019 :-(

Comment: macOS Big Sur is also using 3.81 :-(

Comment: macOS Ventura checking in (3.81) :(

Answer (score 4):

If you are using GNU make, another way to get this effect is to use a make "include" of another makefile:

From Makefile:

```
include "./MyFile.mak"
```

Create a file "MyFile.mak" with content:

```
FILE := "my file content"
FILE += "more content 1"
FILE += "more content 2"
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, I get `Makefile:1: "./MyFile.mak": No such file or directory`

Comment: that probably means you are using a none GNU version of make.... or a really old version of GNU make... try: "make -v"

Comment: using make in mac, not sure if bundled or installed by homebrew, `make -v` gives `GNU Make 3.81`

Comment: do you make sure you have not accidently converted TAB characters into SPACE characters in the Makefile?  Make is almost annoying as python in this regards.

Comment: I got this to work by on my Mac by removing the quotes, e.g.: 

    `include ./MyFile`

Answer (score 3):

As the platform has not been specified, this is the way how it works on Solaris:

```
VERSION:sh = cat VERSION

all:
        echo $(VERSION)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more portable solution, which works with `MAKE` version 3, where `file` directive isn't available. The downside is that it requires creating a temporary file in the process.

```
$(shell echo define my_variable > file.tmp)
$(shell cat my_file.txt >> file.tmp)
$(shell echo endef >> file.tmp)
include file.tmp
```

The main idea is to use `define` directive, which is specifically designed to declare multiline variables. Of course, you can avoid using `shell` and a temporary file if you can explicitly write file contents for Makefile usage.

Keep in mind that, if your file contains `$` signs, `MAKE` will try to expand them as variables/directives when `my_variable` is expanded (or when assigned, of you define it with `:=`). If you want to avoid it, you need to escape them before including file contents. For example, instead of `cat` you can do this:

```
$(shell sed 's/\$$/$$$$/g' my_file.txt >> file.tmp)
```