# How to use #define to define a variable value from a text file?

Tags: c, variables, global-variables

Somewhere in my code I use `int array[L]`. I specify the array length: `#define L 64`. Everything is ok. But what if I want to specify this value 64 in a (external) text file, not in the code? How can I read a text file into #define?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend defining macro values outside the source code. If you absolutely have to, you'd have to open the file read-only and parse the text file to get your value.

Comment: Your code would not compile since L would not pre-process to an integer litteral. By the way, a header file is an external text file. If you want dynamically sized array, this won't work.

Comment: most compilers will let you specify a Macro definition on the command line.  Usually it's -D.  So, in your Makefile, you'll want to read the external file, and parse out the value for L.  Than specify that value as the parameter to the -D compiler flag.  You will soon become a Makefile guru.  Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767413/create-a-variable-in-a-makefile-by-reading-contents-of-another-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what if I want to specify this value 64 in a (external) text file, not in the code?

There are two methods to set the value of a macro that I can think of.

1. Define it in code. A text file won't do for this purpose.
2. Define it as command line option in the compiler (`-DL=64`).

   If you use `make`, you can define the option in the appropriate `Makefile`.

   If you use an IDE, you'll need to figure out how to do that in the various settings that IDEs provide.

Answer (score 0):

Read the text file, and then `malloc` the array:

```
int *array; 
int L; 
int main(void)
{ 
    L = readLengthFromTextFile();
    array = malloc( L );
    if ( array == NULL ) {
        printf( "array allocation failed\n" );
        exit(1);
    }

    // use the array as if declared as:    int array[L];

    free( array );
}
```