# How to stop Makefile from expanding my shell output?

Tags: makefile

By running this:

```
GITIGNORE_CONTENTS = $(shell while read -r line; do printf "$$line "; done < "$(.gitignore)")

all:
    echo $(GITIGNORE_CONTENTS)
```

The contents of the variable `GITIGNORE_CONTENTS` are the expanded version of the ignore patterns on my `.gitignore` file, i.e., `myfile.txt` instead of `*.txt`

I am using this solution because none of the solution on the question [Create a variable in a makefile by reading contents of another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767413/create-a-variable-in-a-makefile-by-reading-contents-of-another-file) work.

This solution works inside a make rule to print the file names, but not put them inside a variable:

```
all:
    while read -r line; do \
        printf "$$line "; \
    done < ".gitignore"
    echo $(GITIGNORE_CONTENTS)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue of shell's wildcard expansion, not of make's. Consider this,

```
GITIGNORE_CONTENTS:=$(shell cat .gitignore)

.PHONY: all
all:
    echo "$(GITIGNORE_CONTENTS)"
    # or alternatively:
    #/bin/echo $(GITIGNORE_CONTENTS)
```

Answer (score 0):

By running this:

```
GITIGNORE_CONTENTS = $(shell while read -r line; do printf "$$line "; done < ".gitignore")

all:
    echo "$(GITIGNORE_CONTENTS)"
```

With the following `.gitignore` file:

```
*.txt
*.var
# Comment
*.xml
*.html
```

It correctly outputs:

```
echo "*.txt *.var # Comment *.xml *.html "
*.txt *.var # Comment *.xml *.html
```